# Как перевести длинное число в массив байтов?

Tags: python-3.x, длинная-арифметика

Допустим, у нас есть какое-то число, **точный размер которого неизвестен**:

```
>>> import random

>>> a = random.randint(2**100, 2**1000)
```

Нужно преобразовать его в массив байтов, например:

```
>>> n = 258
>>> b = n.get_bytes(...)
b'\x01\x02'

>>> n = 749520
>>> b = n.get_bytes(...)
b'\x0b\x6f\xd0'
```

Пытался использовать bytes([...]), to_bytes(...), struct.pack(...), но, как я понял во всех вариантах нужно указывать размер массива.

Есть что-нибудь, что автоматически определяет длину числа в байтах и генерирует байт-массив?

Comment: Просто взять логарифм по основанию 2 от числа

Comment: Ай ладно, тоже напишу ответ для разнообразия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import math
n = 749520
print(n.to_bytes(math.ceil(math.log2(n) / 8), 'big'))  # → b'\x0b\x6f\xd0'
```

(работает только для чисел больше нуля)

Answer (score 0):

Кое-что получилось, но, по моему, это велосипед:

```
import struct

def to_bytes(n):
    hex_str = hex(n)[2:]
    if len(hex_str) % 2 == 1:
        hex_str = hex_str.rjust(len(hex_str) + 1, '0')

    numbers = [int(hex_str[i: i + 2], 16) for i in range(0, len(hex_str), 2)]
    return struct.pack('B' * len(numbers), *numbers)


print(to_bytes(749520) == b'\x0b\x6f\xd0')  # True
print(to_bytes(258) == b'\x01\x02')         # True

import random
n = random.randint(2**100, 2**1000)
print(to_bytes(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Канонический способ извлечь байты из неотрицательного числа:

```
def to_bytes(n):
    return n.to_bytes(
        (n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, # сколько нужно байт, что вместить все биты
        byteorder='little'         # порядок байт в строке
    )
```